# JSONP - How to receive response from cross domain?

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp, remote-access

My form is present in  abc.com/activation.php
and request processor page is def.com/request.php
request.php receives value from activation.php, searches database and returns true/false.
Field id in activation.php is "serial_key" 
return value from request.php will be displayed in field id "check" in activation.php

can anybody please provide me a sample jquery-jsonp code snippet to implement the same?

Comment: What did you try? What did Google say? There are loads of tutorials around. We will just google that and copy/paste you a tutorial link, which is what you should do...

Comment: `to implement the same`  .. same as what?  Not clear at all what you are asking or where you are having problems. Post code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

To make your script able to server cross domain in php, you need to set proper header.

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

If it does not work, make sure it is configured properly on you web server config.

Thanks
Amit